# Why am I getting this undefined method in Rails when the method is clearly defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, methods, undefined

I’m using Rails 4.2.4.  I have the below methods in my class …

```
  def self.object_desc_link(event_id, app_id, token, bib_no)
    OBJECT_DESC_LINK_TEMPLATE.sub( %r{events\/([^\\])+}, "events=#{event_id}" )
                             .sub( %r{appid=([^\&])+}, "appid=#{app_id}" )
                             .sub( %r{token=([^\&])+}, "token=#{token}" )
                             .sub( %r{search=([^\&])+}, "search=#{bib_no}" )
  end


  def process_page_data(object_id, content)
    …
      object_desc_link_str = self.object_desc_link(@event_id, @app_id, @token, i)
```

But when it gets to the above line, I get the error

```
undefined method `object_desc_link' for #<MyService:0x007f8cb3584840>
```

The spelling looks correct, so why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might require more information from your class, but from what I can see --

It looks like object_desc_link() is a class method. When it is called in process_page_data() -- which is an instance method -- then self becomes the instance rather than the class.

So you may be getting that error since object_desc_link() doesn't exist as an instance method on instances of that class. It's only available to be called on the class.

It looks like you might want to change object_desc_link() to an instance method, but I can't tell without more information about what you're trying to accomplish.

I hope that helps!